# How to find the number of platform required by given arrival and departure information using python code

Tags: python, list, sortedlist

I have two list having trains timing of arrivals and departure as below:

```
arrival = ["01:00", "01:07", "01:12", "01:14", "01:18", "01:25"]
depart  = ["01:08", "01:10", "01:20", "01:19", "01:40", "01:30"]
```

so here is the first train is arriving at "01:00" and departing at "01:08" and so on
so 2nd trains arriving at "01:07" so it can not be arrive on first platform because on the first platform first train still there,
so third train will arrive at "01:12" so this third train can arrive on first platform because first train already departed at "01:08"

so I need to find the how many platform is require for this number of trains

```
the output is 3
```

Comment: Show us that you tried so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: How about: Loop through every minute over 30 minutes. Every minute check how many trains there are at that time docked. Adjust depending on these two lists. Finally loop through the list and check max value.

Comment: An easy way to do so would be to first convert all time to just minutes as: `hours*60+minutes`. Then, you can either use brute force with two loops and loop every combination until you find the max value of `num_of_trains`, or, use a counter variable, an index variable and a step variable to solve in one go.